# Write php file part name from jQuery $this value

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to 'include' a php file in a html template when a nav-item is selectd. The code below make active the item on click it. What I want to do is, at the same time it becomes active,load the php file with de same name than '$this' value is. I mean:
on click in tab 'two' ($this value), load in div '#contFl' the php file named 'two.php' at time its become 'active'; load 'one.php' on click in 'one' item;...
Tried a few ways of text estructure in 'load(...)' -last one on last code line- with no results. Pleasefull to have some help.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.navbar-nav > li").click(function(e){
        $("ul.navbar-nav > li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#contFl").load('"'+$(this).val()+'.php');
    });
})
```

HTML code of navbar

```
    <div id="collapsibleNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-around">
  <ul id="collUl" class="navbar-nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-1 mb-md-0">
    <li class="nav-item nav-link active" id="uno" role="button"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Inicio</li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-link" id="dos" role="button"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Dos</li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="tres"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle px-2" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> Tres</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Inicio</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="tres.php"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i> Tres</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="dos.php"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Dos</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="cuatro.php"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cuatro</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-link" id="cuatro" role="button"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cuatro</li>
  </ul>
```

Code in template where include new php file.

```
  <?php
include(ASSETS."/navbar.php");
include(ASSETS."/banner.php")?>

<div id="contFl" class="container-fluid">
<!-- HERE THE NEW 'INCLUDE' -->
</div>
```

Comment: `li` elements don't have a `value` property, so `$(this).val()` will always be blank.   Please include your HTML so we can see how you store the file name - you might need `$(this).text()` or `$(this).data("name")`.   **edit** looks like `$(..).val()` will take a numeric `value=` from an `li` (which seems strange) - either way, you won't get the string "two".   See https://jsfiddle.net/r0235gou/ for an example.

Comment: You shouldn't concatenate `"` before the filename.

Comment: From your edit: `$("#contFl").load(this.id+'.php');`  but won't work for three as it has a submenu and that submenu has what appears to be invalid html: `<ul><a>` as well as not being picked up by `$("ul.navbar-nav > li")`

Comment: Thanks for quick answers. @freedomn-m, I saw and try jsfiddle example, adding 'value' to <li>...no results.About `(this.id+'.php')` no results too, even restarting Apache server. By now, I'm not considering apply to submenus, but take note about invalid html to check it. Thanks @Barman too. Apologies about my lack of skills in jQuery...may will try with javascript...

Comment: Add some debugging - before your `$(..).load` check what `this.id` is

Comment: OK, got it!! Debug helps much to understand. With `(this.id+'.php')` finnally works. I had some added issues with path to php files. Once solved path issues, I reach target . Thanks a lot.